# Or operator criteria in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I updated my Spring Data Mongodb reactive example to the latest Spring Boot(2.5.6), there is a [findByKeyword](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-mongo/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java#L133) method to use `regex` to match Post title and content.

```java
 Flux<Post> findByKeyword(String q) {
    var reg = ".*" + q + ".*";
    return template.find(query(where("title").regex(reg).orOperator(where("content").regex(reg))),
        Post.class);
  }
```

And add a [test method](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-mongo/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostRepositoryPageableTest.java#L72) to verify it, it did not work in the latest version.

```java
  public void testFindByKeyword() {
    this.postRepository.findByKeyword("title")
        .skip(0)
        .take(10)
        .log()
        .as(StepVerifier::create)
        .expectNextCount(10)
        .verifyComplete();
  }
```

In another method [`findByTitleContains`](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/0c816aef869c4b5bfbc5ac1beaff4ca505209da9/boot-mongo/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java#L139), it did not use `orOperator` and worked well.

I am not sure what is changed in `orOperator` the past versions, it was working well in the old versions(Spring Boot 2.1 or 2.2).

Comment: Can you update your question by also mentioning the old and new versions?

Comment: the above creates a query like that connects `title` to an `OR` criteria array with only one element. In which version did this work before?
Also please try something like `new Criteria().orOperator(where("title").regex(reg), where("content").regex(reg))`